# Turbolinks 5 doesn't work on some links

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks, turbolinks-5

I cannot find any answer on this seemingly easy question. In my rails5 app some links do use turbolinks for loading new page. But some just launch full page reload.

There is no js attached to that links, turbolinks is not disabled on that links.

This link **uses turbolinks**:

```
= link_to qm_input_path('hour') do ...
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/qimen/hour/input"> ...
```

In the action it has

```
render layout: 'input'
```

And this link **doesn't**:

```
= link_to qm_chart_path(@foo, @bar), class: 'btn btn-default pull-right next' do ...
<a class="btn btn-default pull-right next" href="/qimen/hour/chart/foo/bar"> ...
```

In the action it has

```
render layout: guess_layout
```

So, nothing explicitly blocking turbolinks to work.

Why?

Comment: Are you using a different JavaScript file or a different stylesheet in your `guess_layout` compared to your `input` layout?

Comment: Both `'input'` and `guess_layout` give the same `<head>`. Js and styles are included by simple `stylesheet_link_tag`, `javascript_include_tag`. Among them there is `= javascript_include_tag 'https://maps.googleapis.com.....'`. But this `<head>` is used in all layouts.
My `guess_layout` only resolves to `'print'` if param `?print=1` is given in the url. And then `<head>` has additional js to launch print window on page open. But in my use case I don't go there. I just press `.next` link, that simply browses to similar pages. And page reloads totally.

Comment: Yes, a link to the site which demonstrates the problem. Or if you can create a new app which demonstrates the problem that would also be fine

Comment: [Go here](http://ksg.qmdj.biz/qimen/hour/chart/2017-06-03T15:27:48+03:00/St.%20Petersburg/30.335098600000038)

Login alm.ays
Pass 12345678

Then use Previous / Next buttons below the white table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145771/discussion-between-dom-christie-and-dahan).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the `href`s in your links contain periods (`.`).

Turbolinks will only handle links that it considers to be HTML. That is, those that have no extension (e.g. `/post/1234`), or those which have an `html`/`htm`/`xhtml` after the last period (e.g. `/post/1234.html`). In your case, the links which are performing a full page load end with something like: `/30.335098600000038`. Turbolinks will not consider this to be an HTML resource and so will not handle it.

To solve this, I'd recommend using query strings for parameters that may contain periods. For example to tidy up one of your links, you could try:

```
qimen/hour/chart?time=2017-06-03T15:27:48+03:00&city=St.%20Petersburg&longitude=30.335098600000038
```